# displaying an image inline in TextArea.htmlText

Tags: apache-flex, htmltext

I would like to display some smiley's inbetween text in my chatbox but when i add an image it gets displayed on a seperate line...

Any ideas?

```
<mx:TextArea id="myChat" width="271" height="238" backgroundColor="#ffffff" borderThickness="0" editable="false" enabled="true" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" wordWrap="true">
    <mx:htmlText>
    <![CDATA[
         <font size='14'> some text - </font><img src='images/emoticons/wink_smile.gif' height='15' width='15'/><font size='14'> more text</font>
    ]]>                      
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:TextArea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Flash's support for the `img` tag in text fields is subpar; even in [the official Flex 3 documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html) it says:

> *"Note: The <img> tag is not fully
>   supported, and might not work in some
>   cases."*

There's [an issue in the Adobe bug tracker](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-620) that seems to describe the exact problem you're having.

In any case, [Valentin Manthei seems to have a solution](http://www.valentin-manthei.de/as3/SmileArea.as) for this. I haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: I'm aware of the poor html support, i'm almost certain there must be a simple hack
These guys have done it somehow: http://www.flashcomguru.com/commchat.cfm

Comment: I agree that there must be a hack to get this to work, but I'm not sure it'll be simple ;) You should check out that SmileArea class by Valentin Manhei though.