# Problem with gif images in cfform

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

The funny thing is the jpg images show up, but the gif images won't. whyyy???

```
<cfform name="theForm" action="" format="flash" skin="haloorange" height="1450" width="850"> 
   <cfformgroup type="tile" style="horizontalGap:5; verticalGap:10; horizontalAlign:center; verticalAlign:middle;">
  <cfoutput query="qryImg">
    <cfformgroup type="vdividedbox" >
       <cfformitem type="html" height="230" width="134" >
         #name#<br/>
         <img src="thumbs/#qryImg.name#"  height="92"/><br/>
         <cfinput name="del#currentRow#" type="checkbox" label="Delete #name#" width="100" align="middle">
       </cfformitem>
    </cfformgroup>
  </cfoutput>
  </cfformgroup>
</cfform>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does the generated source of the form actually look like? Can you reduce the problem to one image tag that's a working jpeg, and one that's a non-working gif?

Comment: ColdFusion creates a swf file for the flash cfform on the fly. if i remove the format="flash" skin="haloorange" and put format="html" then i can see the gif files. it has something to do with format="flash".

Comment: also, if i create a cfm page with  <cfoutput query="qryImg">
#name#<br/>
<img src="thumbs/#qryImg.name#"  height="92"/><br/>
</cfoutput>    i can see all of the images

Comment: pls stop using Flash Form... http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/8/19/Please-stop-using-Flash-Forms

Comment: somebody already created this application and i am here to add more functionality. project owner doesn't have time to rewrite the whole application.

Comment: I hesitate to suggest it, but if flash forms are a requirement, what about using cfinput type="image"? It sounds like underlying flex img support might be spotty. Even in later versions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258418/displaying-an-image-inline-in-textarea-htmltext/258463#258463

Comment: swell.this works: <cfinput type="image" src="thumbs/#qryImg.name#" name="#NewName#" height="92"> . Leigh if you put this into an answer, I will accept it. thanks

Comment: Done (..extra characters because SO hates brevity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hesitate to suggest it, but if flash forms are a requirement, what about using `<cfinput type="image">`? It sounds like [the underlying flex  support might be spotty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258418/displaying-an-image-inline-in-textarea-htmltext/258463#258463). Even in later versions.